# SlickNav plugin not applying Js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-plugins, slicknav

I am trying to implement Slicknav plugin on a website, but it seems not to be loading the js, or not applying required actions defined by it. I have prepared a [LIVE DEMO](http://germanalvarez.net/clinicaimagen/slick.html) with just the HTML code of the nav, as specified on [SlickNav's website](http://slicknav.com/)

The only things added on the [DEMO](http://germanalvarez.net/clinicaimagen/slick.html) are the HTML code, the piece of script on it to run the nav, and the js and css files to make it work, as specified on editors website:

HTML

```
   <ul id="menu2">
    <li>Parent 1
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">item 3</a></li>
            <li>Parent 3
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">item 8</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">item 9</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">item 10</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">item 4</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">item 1</a></li>
    <li>non-link item</li>
    <li>Parent 2
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">item 5</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">item 6</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">item 7</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Script piece on the html file:

```
<script>
$('#menu2').slicknav({
    label: '',
    duration: 1000,
    easingOpen: "easeOutBounce", //available with jQuery UI
    prependTo:'#menu2'
});
</script>
```

Js and Css linked

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/slicknav.css" />
<script src="js/jquery.slicknav.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: try adding all the js files at the bottom like `view-source:http://slicknav.com/`

Comment: Thank you, solved. If you want to post the answer i'll tick, in other case I'll make an auto answer.

Answer (score 1):

Solution: setting scripts at the bottom of the file

@Vitorino Fernandes: try adding all the js files at the bottom like view-source:http://slicknav.com/